# correlation function always NA

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the correlations with this function but I just get NA for each input:

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {

  filenames <- list.files(directory, pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
  csv <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)

  correlations <- c()
  c(correlations, lapply(csv, function(x){
    cor(x$nitrate,x$sulfate) 
    print(cor(x$nitrate,x$sulfate))
  }))

  correlations  
}
```

If I change the function to print the nitrate and sulfate it does in fact have values, if I just pass in x to the cor function it complains about non-numeric values.

Why does it always print NA and not the actual correlation?

Comment: ...also, if your variables have even _one_ missing value (i.e. `NA`) then the correlation will be `NA`. Note the `use` argument to `cor`.

Comment: ...Andrie's observation may not have been involved in the NA issue, but it was a good point regardless.

Comment: Is this [**coursera assignment part 3**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/226738297/Assignment)? Regarding asking people on SO to do your homework, please read [**this**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812)

Comment: @Henrik, yes it is. I'm not asking anyone to do it for me, I'd just like insight in to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It is the missing use "complete.obs" that was what I was missing. @joran - if you move your comment to an answer, I'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `cor` has an argument `use`, which controls how it deals with missing observations, i.e. `NA`s. You might try setting it to `use = "complete.obs"`.